# ASP.NET application with credit card payments

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, credit-card

I might go into a web project that involves credit card transactions, which I have not done previously. The transaction will go through Authorize.NET or may be PayPal.

During user log-in will Forms Authentication be sufficient?

What are other considerations/.NET technologies, particularly with security that I need to research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is unnecessary unless you need to keep track of orders per specific user.  Some eCommerce systems like [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx) allow guest transactions, for example.  What you do need is a [SSL certificate](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/index.html) from a reputable certificate authority.  The rest can be gathered by looking at some [code samples](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/) like Authorize.Net has.